# Why did Venom only eat heads?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, venom

Venom needs food for himself other than food taken by Eddie for himself. Sometimes Venom prefers human flesh as food while Eddie has no interest in it.

In one scene when Eddie crashed with his motorcycle and Treece was about to capture him, Venom takes over and tries to eat Treece,saying

> Eyes. Lungs. Pancreas. So many snacks, so little time.

So that makes me think, that Venom is ready to eat whole body of a human and he likes all of them.

My question is, why he only eat people's heads even when he likes every organ and also eating whole body is more food rather than just going for the head.

I know in the scene I mentioned above, he ate head of the one Drake's thug and he didn't have much time for eat whole human. but in later scenes Venom had enough time to eat whole human but he just bites off heads and eats'em.

Even in the final scene, we see Venom's desires on eating humans and he expresses he like to eat all. (and I think he *did* ate the whole bad guy at Mrs Chen's shop).

> We will eat both your arms, and then both of your legs, and we will
>   eat your face right off your head. You will be this armless, legless,
>   faceless thing,rolling down the street,like a turd,in the wind.

Then why we mostly see Venom eat/bites off just only heads?

Comment: Cannibalism if done for more than a moment on-screen will be off-putting for the audience. He bites people's head off & the scene cuts to imply that he eats people. But if the scene continues for minutes to venom actually crunching heads, limbs, legs & digesting it in his mouth, that would be very uncomfortable to watch for any audience

Comment: We can see few scenes that he just bites heads off and throw away the rest of the body. at the end he completely ate that thug and it wasnt showed in 100% context.  And if that was the case, he may not able to always eat people starting from head. so sometimes it should've shown he bites arms or legs or ears off etc..

Comment: Then maybe he bites head off first to kill people as a merciful act rather than torturing them painfully by eating rest of the body parts & then killing them by eating their head

Comment: He didn't have any mercy for people who was killed by him remember? we see at the end only that Eddie make up a rule that he cannot go and kill/eat anyone he wanted,but he can do that only for bad guys. even after that, Venom couldn't have any mercy for *bad guys*

Comment: Maybe it's the best cost-effective method. Fast kill, and he also gets to eat something.

Comment: @Frost could be true when in a scenario he has to move fast. but what about a scenario (also mentioned in the question), if he has enough time?

Answer (score 5):

As Venom is a comicbook adaptation, this is most likely a nod to the actual Venom comics where Venom is depicted as "needing a certain chemicals found in brains" and is actually shown eating a human head for brains (which he later pukes out). This is showin in "Venom: The Hunger" #1.

He also threatens Spider-Man by saying "We want to eat your BRAIN!" in the "Amazing Spider-Man" issue 333.

Source and images from the comic:
https://www.cbr.com/did-venom-ever-actually-eat-brains/

Comment: great insight from comic book pov